# Strange fonts and keyboard input in some cells of power point

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I an forced to use a template in ppt and in some cells of the template I get a very extrange behaviour:

- "Click to add subtitle" appears in very rare fonts
- When I press some letters in my keyboard, for example "s", other letters appear in the screen.

I attach an screenshot. Any idea what could be happening?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this still happen when you change the font or when you write in a new document?

Comment: No, it works as expected. Changing a new font, or starting a new doc solved the issue. Unfortunately I have to use that template

Comment: You could try re-installing the font that is being used. I am thinking the font file that is used inside the PowerPoint is corrupt.

Comment: There's likely some kind of font substitution going on.  Basically, it probably means you don't have the font installed that is used in that particular template.  Also note that MS Office applications aren't graphic design software.  For future reference, SuperUser is probably the best stack exchange site for asking such questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately didn't solve it